# Why is ssh not built into windows?

Tags: windows, ssh

SSH is built into most POSIX style operating systems. I know SSH functionality can be added to windows using tools such as Putty, but is there any reason, commercial or otherwise, why ssh is not built into windows as it is in other operating systems?

Comment: Why Windows doesn't come with a default program for SSH? Not possible to know without asking the developers, I guess...

Answer (score 6):

It is not built into any system. Most Linux distribution just ship openssh-client (and -server) as a package by default.

Since Windows comes with a default userland (Explorer, Media Player, etc), they don't ship external packages like openSSH.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that Windows is not POSIX compliant (without add-ons like Cygwin).  Windows is geared at a GUI environment rather than a command line shell, at least for now.

Comment: Windows NT is POSIX.1-compliant (although .1 is not very useful), and the latest Server editions have a very-mimimal-GUI mode (Server Core) aiming towards a pure CLI server in future releases.

Comment: I'll clarify that it's not fully POSIX compliant.  For details on what the .1 means take a look at this wikipedia entry - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems

Answer (score 2):

Because Microsoft prefer to provide GUI based tools for remote use of Windows. In particular Remote Desktop Protocol / Terminal Services.

Historically, Microsoft have not, on the whole, been enthusiastic supporters or adopters of products and standards originating in the Unix or Internet communities.